# Find Monitor Size In Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, dimensions

I'm trying to find out the actual physical size (width and height in mm) of my monitor using the system software only. The reason for this is I'm currently accessing a video player from a bigger size monitor and its restricting access to any monitor having size greater that 530x300mm as seen in screenshot.

[image]

So I was wondering from which source is this appliciation is able to acces the physical size of the monitor, and whether i could make changes to it so as to it would not block viewing.

I tried looking at the device manager/monitor section & the system information page yet found no details whatsoever. So if you know how to do the same, please help me out.

Comment: Start>Run type in msinfo32 and hit ok, then go to Components>Multimedia>Display>Resolution

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered already:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019346/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-physical-size-of-the-monitor

The basic method is using `getdevicecap`:

```
GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(GetDesktopWindow), VERTSIZE)
GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(GetDesktopWindow), HORZSIZE)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps?redirectedfrom=MSDN

This can be not exact if drivers are not correctly installed.

Comment: Can I alter this information in any way using the regedit? or any other software application? or even just spoof it so apps can't fetch the real value?

Comment: You do realize you are asking us to tell you how to possibly illegally bypass a security measure? I'll only say this: Display Pixels per Inch